# Google Sheet Time Tracker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

What code do I need to add in order to toggle buttons to run a script for the "time clock" to start, end, reset, and print those results in the worksheet?

- Layout and design
- Linked buttons to functions within the script editors
- Wrote the script in the script editor
- Tested printing function

---

```
/** This time tracker macro was built to help to edit during podcast speed up production workflow.*/


/** Records and prints, the value of the button pressed and files columns with the host or guest, date, timecode, and reason. Prints the value in A1*/
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}
function getValue(cellName) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).getValue();
}
function getNextRow() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastRow() +1;
}

/**Host and guest buttons. Trigger this button to start process of labeling in A1 cell*/ 
function host() {
  setValue('A1', 'Host');
}
function guest1() {
  setValue('A1', 'Guest 1');
}
function guest2() {
  setValue('A1', 'Guest 2');
}
function guest3() {
  setValue('A1', 'Guest 3');
}
function addRecord(a, b, c) {
  var row = getNextRow();
  setValue('A' + row, a);
  setValue('B' + row, b);
  setValue('C' + row, c);
}

    /** Timecode clock*/
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

function  countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes){
  while (minutes >=0){   
     sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes);     
    while (seconds >= 0 ){     
      var m = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
      var s = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
      if (m === 'pausing' || s === 'pausing'|| m === 'reset' || s === 'reset' ) {
       return
      }      
      sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds); 
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(1000)
      seconds --
    }    
    seconds = 59;
    minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
    minutes --
  }
}

function startTimer(){
   var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
   var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
   countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes)
   setValue('A1', 'Start');
}

function pause(){
   var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
   var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('pausing');  
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('pausing');   
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   Utilities.sleep(1000);
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes)
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds)
   setValue('A1', 'Pause');
}

function reset(){
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('reset');  
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('reset');   
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   Utilities.sleep(1000);
   sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(0)
   sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(0)
   setValue('A1', 'Reset');
}

function end() {
  setValue('A1', 'End');
}


/**Reason. Trigger this button to end process of labeling so printed result starts with A1 cell*/
function micnoiseIn() {
    addRecord(getValue('A1'), new Date(), 'Microphone Noise');
  }
function mouthnoiseIn() {
    addRecord(getValue('A1'), new Date(), 'Pop or Mouth Noise');
  }
function stammerIn() {
    addRecord(getValue('A1'), new Date(), 'Stammering');
  }
function stammerOut() {
    addRecord(getValue('A1'), new Date(), 'Stopped Stammering');
```

I expect the out to be

Press Start A1 cell 'start' clock starts
Printed A2 Start | B2 00:00:00 | C2 Start

"End
Printed A* End | B2 Timecode | C* End

Press Host + Microphone Noise with A1 Host
Printed A* Host | B2 Timecode | C* Microphone Noise

[image: GoogleSheet Time Tracker]

Comment: I'd rather everything just trigger from drawn buttons and the functions. I noticed this user was attempting to use html code.

 [Stack Overflow User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776051/google-sheets-time-tracker-update-1)


And this youtube link got me started
[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmGfkst7qRc)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Can you provide your current issue of your script? And is this information useful for your situation? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/52e7bbdabf8bfc34ac16d5f27fd8cb80

Comment: I stared rigging something together to track notes during rough edits for podcast. I thought about it, and came to idea that gsheets would be best because I make the notes on the fly and not worry about pressing host and mic noise and I know somewhere around that logged time there's an edit that needs to be made.

My buddy mentioned: Create a stop and start button... and then as many other buttons you want... and have them all write to their own cells with a value of NOW() and then use formulas to output. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en

Comment: @Tanaike thank you. Question, could I link the functions to buttons within gsheets instead of having an html "toast" pop up?

Comment: Thank you for replying. You can assign the function to the image on the Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.